# How to update the version in Zenodo?

Tags: github, zenodo

I have released a Release `v1.0.0` on github. And got its DOI in Zenodo. But now I have added some scripts and released v1.0.1. But when I check it in Zenodo, it still shows v1.0.0. How can I update this version and get DOI?

The repository is https://github.com/Yujie-Cui/WB-channels
[image]

In addition, when I click upload at the front of the page, it shows
[image]

The public here shows 0. But the draft shows 1. The draft shows what I posted. But I have obtained the earliest version of DOI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The documentation on the Zenodo homepage doesn't seem to explain this explicitly but the [documentation on Github](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/archiving-a-github-repository/referencing-and-citing-content) does: **Zenodo creates releases from the releases on Github**, so to update your entry on Zenodo, you need to create a new release on Github.

Comment: Correct. Just create a new release and it'll automatically update in Zenodo. If you linked the Zenodo DOI in your GitHub readme, the link will take you to the same site but with the updated version